# Git, how to commit only a specific directory?

Tags: git, github

in my rails app I have a /public/assets directory. I'm writing a rake task to compile and push assets. After all the assets are generated I want to checkin and push ONLY the assets folder to github.

I have been using:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "assets"
git push
```

Any ideas on how I can update this to only check-in and push /public/assets ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be simple:

```
git add public/assets
git commit -m "assets"
git push
```

Please note that this only works, when you didn't stage (`add`) any other files prior to committing.

Comment: -a will add everything that has been modified or deleted, but not new files.

Comment: Sorry, dumb copy and pasting. Thanks.

Comment: @AnApprentice, see the documentation. `git commit -a` commits all modified tracked files, in addition to all already staged changes.

Comment: This question and answer pair are pretty much the embodiment of why telling everyone "Just run `git commit -a`!" as so many tutorials do is not an ideal introduction to Git.

Comment: So how do you commit only a single folder (even if you have staged a bunch of other folders) ? Maybe you want to write a separate commit note for a particular folder of the 1000 in the staging area. :)